# Unable to evaluate a string using eval() in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to hash a string and salt using a custom algorithm which is user supplied. However, the `$algo` variable always appears as a string and thus the output is clearly the value of the input as a string.

```
<form method='POST'>
    <input type='text' name='pass'>
    <input type='text' name='salt'>
    <input type='text' name='algo'>
    <input type='submit' value='Hash'>
</form>

<?php

$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$salt = $_POST['salt'];
$algo = $_POST['algo'];

eval('echo $algo;');
```

Comment: write eval("\$algo\") & check..

Comment: eval("\$algo = \"$algo\";");
echo $algo;

Comment: I've omitted the double quotes. Sorry for the lame question. It's just that I'm used to single quotes and sometimes this turns out a bad practice. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to pass the variable $algo in your string, you need to use double quote "

```
eval("echo $algo;");
```